# regading ubuntu installation

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I was trying to install ubuntu but unfortunately, am unable to do so on my VMware workstation 16 pro. I tried with VMWare 15 pro, and to my surprise, it worked. But the thing is I want to install it on VMWare 16 since I have already installed other OS there. Previously, I was using the same VMWare on a different computer and ubuntu was working there, now I uninstall VMWare from the old computer and install it on a new computer. So, can anyone please guide me??? Thanks!

The OS of the new computer is Windows 10 Education. I successfully installed the ubuntu 20.04.2.0 live-server on the VMware workstation 16 but ubuntu-desktop 20.04.2.0 isn't installing. Please let me know if my question is still incomplete.

Comment: "*unable to do so*" is a bit too vague to offer useful advice.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which OS is the new computer running? At what stage does the installation fail? What is the exact error message? Without these information in your question, no one can give you an answer.

Comment: The VMWare 15/16 is useful advice, **once** the *unstated* release of Ubuntu is known (are you talking server? desktop? specialist release? which release? etc) however you're missing required specifics...